# Button hover don't work with transparent

Tags: html, css

I have this code below that consists of a simple html button with a hover effect. What i'm trying to accomplish is that when i hover my mouse over the button it will become transparent with a white border. I don't know why my code doesn't work no matter how i change it. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

But when i do it the other way around

```css
     body{
            background-color: red;
        }
        .upload-btn-wrapper {
            margin-top: 20px;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .btn {
            color: white;
            border: 1px solid white;
            background-color: black;
            padding: 8px 20px;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .upload-btn-wrapper:hover {
            background-color: transparent;
            border: 1px solid white;
            color: white;
        }

        .upload-btn-wrapper input[type=file] {
            font-size: 100px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            opacity: 0;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>

    <div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
        <button id="uploadbtn" class="btn">Upload CV!</button>
        <input type="file" name="myfile" />
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you put background on `.btn`, but on hover you change background of wrapper, not button itself. Change selector to `.upload-btn-wrapper:hover .btn`

```css
body{
            background-color: red;
        }
        .upload-btn-wrapper {
            margin-top: 20px;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .btn {
            color: white;
            border: 1px solid white;
            background-color: black;
            padding: 8px 20px;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .upload-btn-wrapper:hover .btn {
            background-color: transparent;
            border: 1px solid white;
            color: white;
        }

        .upload-btn-wrapper input[type=file] {
            font-size: 100px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            opacity: 0;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>

    <div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
        <button id="uploadbtn" class="btn">Upload CV!</button>
        <input type="file" name="myfile" />
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your css:

```
#uploadbtn:hover {
background: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. You can do what YOU WANT WITH HOVER with some animation

It happens due to the input type=file. As we are unable to select that element by id, try to select by tag name `input[type=file]`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    .button {
        width:180px;
        color: white;
        padding: 16px 32px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin: 4px 2px;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
        transition-duration: 0.8s;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .button1 {
        background-color: red; 
        color: black; 
        border: 2px solid red;
    }
    .button2 {
        background-color: green; 
        color: black; 
        border: 2px solid #008CBA;
    }
    .button3 {
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
        color: black; 
       border: 4px double blue;
           
    }
    .button1:hover {
        background-color: transparent;
        color: red;
    }
    input[type=file]:hover,.button2:hover {
        background-color: transparent;
        color: transparent;'
    }
    .button3:hover {
        background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
        color: white;
         border:none;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>transperant animated button</h1>
    <div>
        <button class="button button1">background hide</button>
        <input type="file" name="myfile" />
    </div>
    <br>
    <button class="button button2">background and text hide</button><br>
    <button class="button button3">border hide with color change </button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the background-color on hover be inherit not transparent.Such as:

```
.upload-btn-wrapper:hover .btn {
            background-color: inherit;
            border: 1px solid white;
            color: white;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

It is because your applying :hover rule on the wrong element

change it to

```
#uploadbtn:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid white;
    color: white;
}
```

Plus your input[type="file"] is being overlapped on the button. Add the following css to overcome it

```
.upload-btn-wrapper input[type=file]
{
    z-index : -1;
}
#uploadbtn{
    z-index : 99;
}
```

Comment: And how you activate file input clicking on button in this case?

Comment: file input clicking can be activated by jquery script on button click

Comment: Why to use additional JS if it can be done without JS?